# How to call landline or mobile numbers from the internet?

Tags: software-rec, website

How can I make calls to landline or mobile numbers from the internet? Is there any free providers in UK? Primarily for India

Comment: Nice Edit Diago , if We have nice edit badge  you should get it for  this edit;)

Comment: LOL @ "Please learn to capitalize" comments in edit, and random capitalisation in response from joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080323055302AAFe5Nr

```
If you're on the PC and they are on a phone:

Go to https://www.gizmocall.com/

Steps from their site:
1. Go to Gizmo Call and login or register
2. Type the telephone number of the person you want to be able to call you.
(They can be in any country around the world.)
3. Immediately a free local number for that country is assigned and displayed 
  to you
4. The person you called can now call you back using this new local number
```

Note : That all for 20 mins

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of providers, but most are not free.

- [Skype](http://skype.com) - Calls to India are 0.054 GBP/minute including VAT (or 0.106 USD/minute including VAT).
- [Gizmo5](http://gizmo5.com) - Calls to India from a computer are 0.09 USD/minute.
- [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com) - Calls to India are 0.07 USD/minute, however Google Voice requires an existing US number in order to sign up.

Comment: i am looking for free providers. i am aware of these

Answer (score 1):

Use Skype [Skype.com](http://register.skype.com/en-oc-cc/india/1?cm_mmc=PAIDS|GAWS-_-EMEAF|OC|EN-_-CC|OC2IN-_-zf4wbo&gclid=CNW_8J-o4ZwCFYYVzAodriJJlA&T=1252388909&JTID=115312478&OGID=171&network=GAW)

Comment: Not free to landlines and mobiles, but pretty cheap.

Comment: @outsideblasts - it's "free" if you buy the el-cheapo unlimited-per-month outbound calling.. it's <10 USD a month (I think it's only $5)

Answer (score 1):

Considering phone calls arn't free, you'll probably end up having to cover costs one way or the other- and phone companies do profit a fair amount from international calls. Cheap is plausible, but other than google voice and possibly skype, i don't think there's any way to make free calls, and both of those are (or were) US only. You're best off using skype or similar on both ends.

So.. i don't think there is an answer other than 'there isn't one'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [PennyTel](http://www.pennytel.com). If you use an internet connected device like iPhone or your computer, you can make calls to India for 0.02 AUD per minute.

Answer (score 0):

For unlimited free Local and STD call to any mobile or land phone I suggest you to use **Dingaling**. I am using this to make free call. Dingaling only allow ISD call in between US and Canada.

See the link to know how to make [worldwide free local and STD call](http://www.001easytricks.com/2014/05/worldwide-free-local-and-std-call.html).

For best Application to Application call use [Skype](http://www.skype.com). Skype is the best for PC to PC or PC to phone (Must install skype App) call.